# Abrir Formulário em tabcontrol especifica

Tags: c#, winforms

Comando para abrir um formulário em uma tabcontrol especifica.

Exemplo: em um formulário tenho um tabcontrol com duas abas: cadastrar e consultar. Aí queria (com um botão) abrir esse formulário direto na aba consultar.

Comment: coloque o código que você já tem pronto do formulário e de abrir o formulário

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie alguma forma em que o form que será aberto saiba qual a tab que ele precisa selecionar e então selecione-a usando `TabControl.SelectedTab`.

Você pode, por exemplo, passar um `enum` por parâmetro no construtor do form.

Vide:

```
public class Form1 : Form 
{
    public Form1(TipoTab tipoTab)
    {
        if(tipoTab == TipoTab.Cadastro)
        {
            tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabCadastro;
        }
        else
        {
            tanControl1.SelectedTab = tabConsulta;
        }
    }
}

public enum TipoTab
{
    Cadastro,
    Consulta
}
```

E uso seria algo como

```
public static void botaoCadastro_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var form = new Form(TipoTab.Cadastro);
    form.ShowDialog();
}

public static void botaoConsulta_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var form = new Form(TipoTab.Consulta);
    form.ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Não sou expert em C# e também precisei disso, então resolvi assim:
Essa classe localiza um formulário se ele já estiver aberto em uma Tab, se ainda não, adiciona uma nova Tab, abre o formulário e coloca em evidência...

```
    // Abrir formulário em uma aba ou por a aba em evidência
    private void IniciaFormNaAba(Form frm)
    {
        int index = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < tbApp.TabCount; i++)
        {
            if (tbApp.TabPages[i].Text.Trim() == frm.Text.Trim())
            {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(index != -1)
        {
            tbApp.SelectedIndex = index;
        }
        else
        {
            TabPage tabForm = new TabPage { Text = frm.Text };

            tbApp.TabPages.Add(tabForm);

            frm.TopLevel = false;
            frm.Parent = tabForm;
            frm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            frm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            frm.Show();

            // Seleciona a Tab
            tbApp.SelectedIndex = tbApp.TabPages.Count-1;
        }
    }
```

Um botão de comando...

```
    private void btnMedicos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IniciaFormNaAba(new frmMedicos());
    }
```

O resultado é esse...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]